# docker swarm and aws ecr authentication using api keys

Tags: amazon-web-services, authentication, docker, swarm

I'm having trouble pulling docker images from AWS ECR when deploying a stack to my docker swarm cluster that runs in AWS EC2.

If I try to ssh to any of the nodes and authenticate manually and pull an image manually, there are no issues

This works:

```
root@manager1 ~ # `aws ecr get-login --no-include-email --region us-west-2 `
Login Succeeded
root@manager1 ~ # docker pull *****.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/myapp:latest
```

however, if I try deploying a stack or service:

```
docker stack deploy --compose-file docker-compose.yml myapp
```

The image can't be found and on the node that I already authenticated as well as on all other manager/worker nodes.

Error from docker service ps myapp :

```
"No such image: *****.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/myapp:latest"
```

OS: RHEL 7.3 
Docker version: Docker version 1.13.1-cs5, build 21c42d8

Anyone have a solution for this issue?

Answer (score 3):

Try this command

```
docker login -u Username -p password *****.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com && docker stack deploy --compose-file docker-compose.yml myapp --with-registry-auth
```

Comment: I agree with above. I think @Nerses is missing the "--with-registry-auth" parameter which is required for registry authentication.

Comment: But I think this is only available with Docker 17.03 or higher. Might be 17.05, not sure. But it is not there with Docker 1.13.1

Comment: @Mohan Shanmugam, thank you! This didn't work for me, but I've tried the following, which actually worked.  `aws ecr get-login` && docker stack deploy --compose-file docker-compose.yml s --with-registry-auth  Please note, I'm trying not to use user/pass for this, instead, I'd like to use the AWS key/secret. For some reason, I'm not able to use docker login method, even if I use the very same user/pass that is associated with the key that I have in ~/.aws/credentials.

Comment: Yes I give specific to docker repository. For ECS what you have done is right.

Comment: You not able to use aws access key and secret key in accessing ecr repository authentication.  http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/userguide/Registries.html#registry_auth. Will try the alternative ways and update you.

Comment: @Nerses can you update in which context you are using this commands like deploying through jenkins or running this commands from bash